# Laravel connect to remote ssh server

Tags: php, laravel, ssh

I have some struggling with Laravel. I want to connect to remote dedicated server via ssh, if I want that, I would need to specify ip address of this server, user and password. I have multiple dedicated servers that I want to rum commands, they all are specified in database, in my case installing some game servers.
What is your ideas? How would I create connection in controller?
I found LaravelCollective but I didn't find answers how to define ip, user and password.

Code is like:

```
SSH::into('staging')
```

Does it need to look like?

```
SSH::into('x.x.x.x', 'root', 'password)
```

Comment: It's opinion based. But you can try [Laravel Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/envoy)

Comment: I have edited a question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to publish config file :

```sh
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Collective\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider"
```

The configuration file is located at `config/remote.php`, and contains all of the options you need to configure your remote connections. The connections array contains a list of your servers keyed by name.

```php
'connections' => [
    'production' => [
        'host'      => '1.2.3.4',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'key'       => '',
        'keytext'   => '',
        'keyphrase' => '',
        'agent'     => '',
        'timeout'   => 10,
    ],

    'another_server' => [
        'host'      => '4.3.2.1',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'key'       => '',
        'keytext'   => '',
        'keyphrase' => '',
        'agent'     => '',
        'timeout'   => 10,
    ],
],
```

Usage :

```php
SSH::into('production');
SSH::into('another_server');
```